# PHP - How to modify matched pattern and replace

Tags: php, regex

I have string which contain space in its html tags

`$mystr = "＆lt; h3＆gt; hello mom ？＆lt; / h3＆gt;"`

so i wrote regex expression for it to detect the spaces in it

`$pattern = '/(?<=&lt;)\s\w+|\s\/\s\w+|\s\/(?=&gt;)/mi';`

so next i want to modify the matches by removing space from it and replace it, so any idea how it can be done? so that i can fix my string like
`"＆lt;h3＆gt; hello mom ？＆lt;/h3＆gt;"`

i know there is php function `pre_replace` but not sure how i can modify the matches

`$result = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace , $mystr );`

Comment: The question on everybody's lips is of course: How did you end up with a string like that? The idea is that it is always better to prevent these anomalies in the first place.

Comment: `＆` is not equal to `&`. Try `preg_replace_callback('/＆lt;(?:\s*\/)?\s*\w+\s*＆gt;/ui', function($m) { return preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $m[0]); }, $mystr)`.

Comment: To expand upon and analogize KIKO's response: Every time you paper over an issue like this with a kludge instead of fixing the underlying issue, you add another layer onto the house of cards that is your application, and the more trouble you're going to have if there's ever a breeze.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew 's answer is very good to remove ALL spaces between the brackets, but since these are html tags and you need spaces between the tagname and each of the attributes I wonder if the OP really only wants to remove LEADING spaces, in which case `preg_replace('/＆lt;\s+/ui','＆lt;',$mystr)` would do the job

Comment: @ChrisMaurer My regex, `'/＆lt;(?:\s*\/)?\s*\w+\s*＆gt;/ui'`, only deals with tags that have no attributes, like the example in the question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware will it occured during google translation when i translate string from English to Japanese etc then such spacing occur

Comment: You're using [the API](https://cloud.google.com/translate)? Or are you doing the translation manually in the Google web interface? Did you introduce the `＆lt;` and `＆gt;` before the translation? Knowing what your string looked like before the translation could be useful. Whatever I try, I cannot reproduce this. Anyway, tackling this original problem might be the best approach. This looks like [a classic XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ya am using js api for it : `https://github.com/cjrsgu/google-translate-api-browser`
and ya my original string had `&lt;` like this `&amp;lt;h3&amp;gt;hello world &amp;lt;/h3&amp;gt;` as its content is saved in db generated by cke editor

Comment: You could try to use Google translate after you converted `＆lt;`, `&amp;` and `＆gt;` back to `<`, `&` and `>`. Afterwards you can convert it back, if needed. It is possible you don't end up with those spaces when you do that. The Google translater knows about HTML, but not about HTML entities. See: [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the tip was not aware of `preg_replace_callback` its very helpful

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ok thanks i will try that :)

Comment: If you need more help with this, please drop a comment here or under the answer below with explanation of the issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no thanks the problem is solved thanks to you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific tags like you showed, you can use

```php
preg_replace_callback('/＆lt;(?:\s*\/)?\s*\w+\s*＆gt;/ui', function($m) { 
    return preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $m[0]); 
}, $mystr)
```

The regex - note the `u` flag to deal with Unicode chars in the string - matches

- `＆lt;` - a literal string
- `(?:\s*\/)?` - an optional sequence of zero or more whitespaces and a `/` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `＆gt;` - a literal string.

The `preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $m[0])` line in the anonymous callback function removes all chunks of whitespaces (even those non-breaking spaces).

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it simple and do:

```
$output = str_replace(['＆lt; / ', '＆lt; ', '＆gt; '],
                      ['＆lt;/',   '＆lt;',  '＆gt;'], $input);
```